# Matlab Stepinfo Function

Tags: matlab

```
S = stepinfo(Y,T,180,'SettlingTimeThreshold',ST) ;

ts=S.SettlingTime;
```

in this does it mean ts is the time at which |Y-180| becomes less than ( ST/100 )or something else...
in my code though |Y-180| is less than ST/100 but i am getting ts = NAN;
pls help me out

My code:

```
if ee(end)>160

    S = stepinfo(ee,times,180,'SettlingTimeThreshold',0.01);

else

    S = stepinfo(ee,times,0.5,'SettlingTimeThreshold',1);

end

settling_time = S.SettlingTime;

end
```

where 'ee' is an array of values at each 'times'

ee is basically error angle which becomes 180 or 0 after some time..
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help:

> The response has settled when the error |y(t) - yfinal| becomes
>   smaller than a fraction ST of its peak value.

This means that it's the fraction of the peak error value, not an absolute threshold - e.g. if your system was something that started at around 30, and eventually rose and settled at near 180 (yfinal = 180), then the max error is 150, and the threshold would be 0.01*150 = 1.5.  So it would need to get to 178.5 (180-1.5).

If your system started at 100 and settled at about 180, your max error is 80, and the threshold is then only 0.8, so your value needs to be at 179.2.

Look at what your min(ee) and max(ee) are and then decide on what a sensible threshold is.

EDIT:

If you want to set a fixed threshold you'll have to calculate it on the fly:

```
desiredthreshold = 1.8 % absolute value, e.g. 0.01*180
maxerror = 180-min(ee); % assuming your values are all between 0 and 180
actualthreshold = 1.8/maxerror; %if your min value is 0 then this goes to 0.01, otherwise it will be larger
```

Comment: "thanks" but is their a way to use absolute threshold i.e error less than 0.01*180 or 0.05*180 ....

Comment: do u know how to add absolute threshold that is the error much be less than 2-3 degrees

Comment: how do i use this actual threshold to calculate my settling time

Comment: Just put "actualthreshold" in place of ST - e.g. if you want an absolute threshold of 2 degrees, desiredthreshold = 2, actualthreshold will turn out to be something like 0.01... (or similar)